# Custom sh script not called from systemd service in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: systemd, services

I'm trying to create/run a service, i.e start a script on boot using systemd.

First, when I test my script with `$ /usr/bin/pastec.sh`, it works well.

So, I tried to create my service:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/pastec.service
```

It looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Pastec Service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/pastec.sh
Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then, to launch it:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable pastec.service
systemctl start pastec
```

The code is executed, no error is returned.

```
root# systemctl start pastec
root#
```

But the service/task doesn't exist when I run `ps aux | grep pastec`

NOTE: I was running this script at startup using init.d on Ubuntu 14.04 - Now I want to run it on Ubuntu 18.04 using systemd.

What did I miss ?

EDIT 1: as queried by PonJar, this is what I can see with `systemctl status pastec`

```
● pastec.service - Pastec Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/pastec.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) since Wed 2019-10-02 06:01:07 UTC; 4s ago
  Process: 8339 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pastec.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 8339 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

But no trace of pastec with grep...

Comment: What do you get from "systemctl status pastec"? That will give you an idea of what is happening

Comment: Hi PonJar. I edited my first post with the answer to your question.

Comment: `status` in your case is useless because it will only show the output from the `sh` script, if you really want to to query the service you'll have to make sure there's an output from the script and that the status action will launch a certain command.

Comment: Hello Yaron. I posted a reply to the question below.

Answer (score 2):

After many searches, I found the answser in this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137028/why-is-my-systemd-unit-loaded-but-inactive-dead).

I added `Type=forking` in the Service directive and the script was really launched by the service.

```
Main PID: 12645 (pastec)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/pastec.service
           └─12645 ./pastec visualWordsORB.dat
```

> While the default Type=simple works for many
>   Systemd service files, it does not work when the script in ExecStart
>   launches another process and completes, as is the case with graphite's
>   carbon-cache.py. In these cases you need to explicitly specify
>   Type=forking in the [Service] section so that Systemd knows to look at
>   the spawned process rather than the initial one.